# How do I conveniently create a filter based on the mailing list headers in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail

I am subscribed to many mailing lists, which usually provide special MIME headers such as "List-ID:" , "List-Post:", etc. to signify the E-mail was sent to me through the mailing list. Now, I'm now trying out Mozilla Thunderbird and the problem is that I don't see a way to conveniently create a filter based on the mailing list headers by right-clicking on a message and selecting the "Filter E-mails from this mailing list".

Such menu options exist in other clients such as KDE's KMail and Google's GMail.

I tried some searches such as http://www.google.com/search?q=thunderbird+filter+%22based+on+mailing+list but could not find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually create a filter on any message header:

> http://en.flossmanuals.net/thunderbird/ch029_filters/

View the message source to be able to see all the headers, there's usually one there that specifically identifies the mailing list.

Comment: Hi! I requested a _convenient_ way to do that. Looking at the message's headers and then creating a filter for the appropriate ones manually, is not as convenient as what KMail or even GMail offer where I can right click and it will detect that it has a mailing list header and then I can say what its filter will do.

Answer (score 1):

The following Thunderbird addon might be what you are looking to:

https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/mailing-list-manager/

**Mailing List Manager**
[image: screenshot of Mailing List Manager addon]

Comment: I don't see a way to control there which folder each messages goes to. It seems to have a mind of its own, and won't give me a right-click+set filter button.

Comment: You can actually spot the x-list headers and construct you filter rules from these headers.

Answer (score 0):

One shortcut to adding filters is right-clicking on one of the From or To fields and selecting "Create Filter From..." which will start a filter with the address. Then you can decide what to do with it.

Comment: I'm not interested in the From or To fields which are unreliable for mailing lists. I'm interested in the "List-Post" header and related headers.